# Chrome gives a 401 error for manifest.json

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a Flutter UI (Web channel) app that is deployed as a bundled Spring-boot app ( build files dropped into the main/resources folder in the Spring-boot project). The issue I'm facing is that every time I load the app in Chrome and login I see a 401 error pointing to the manifest.json.
I don't face the same issue when I test my UI locally using Android Studio. This setup uses a modified version of the spring-boot app that is running in Docker.

My manifest.json file is :

```json
{
  "name": "ccccc",
  "short_name": "ccccc",
  "start_url": "/#/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#0175C2",
  "theme_color": "#0175C2",
  "description": "basicapp",
  "orientation": "landscape-primary",
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/cd-16.png",
      "sizes": "16x16",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/cd-32png",
      "sizes": "32x32",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/cd-64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/cd-256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the error that I see is :

```json
{"timestamp":"2021-09-30T18:34:24.329+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"","path":"/manifest.json"}
```

I thought this problem was similar to [this](https://medium.com/@aurelien.delogu/401-error-on-a-webmanifest-file-cb9e3678b9f3.) but that fix did not work.
I then removed the reference to manifest.json from my index.html
i e. `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` and **that got rid of the error** but not sure if that is the right thing to do.

Not sure what the issue is here, it does not stop me from logging into the app but it's just an annoyance to see that as the first thing in the console log.
Any help/assistance to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

You should try [this](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin/issues/212)  solution where `<link>` must use `crossorigin="use-credentials"` tag. I was having the same problem that you and this solved it. Hope you too!